# Windows form has focus but doesn't process keyboard events

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, dialog

I have a strange problem:

I have a Form that I open using ShowDialog(). The form is populated with some buttons and comboboxes. One of the comboboxes is set as the ActiveControl of the Form and the Form has focus.

What I want to accomplish is that the user can enter its username immediately after the Form opens (without the need to select the combobox first). However, if I press the keyboard, nothing happens. However, when I first click on the form with the mouse, and then enter something using the keyboard, it works. I already tried a lot of things like calling Select() and Focus() on the form. I even tried to simulate a mouseclick event (OnMouseClick) on the Form without any luck.

Someone has an idea would could be the problem here?

many thanks

Chris

Comment: Could you please provide some code? Please add the snippet where you call `ShowDialog`

Comment: Is it possible that you are to fast/early when you try Focus/Select and the Form/Control isn't (complitely) rendered at that time?

Comment: A form with controls that accept keyboard input can't have focus; focus goes to a particular control ON the form. You want the form to be active, and the combo box to have focus. It might sound like a trivial distinction, but that's why calling Focus() on the form won't do anything.

Comment: Why on earth would `OnMouseClick()` do anything? All you're doing is run the default event handler for that event, but Windows' focus and event system certainly doesn't care about what methods you run on your form.

Comment: Use View + Tab Order.  Click the controls in the order they should be tabbed, clicking the control for the name first.

Comment: The problem is that the following happens: When I run the application, and e.g. my browser is open and in focus, my form (login screen) opens but my browser keeps the focus. What could be the reason for this behaviour? I want to post some code but the problem is that the code runs fine in isolation so posting it is pretty useless I guess. The form itself is not the problem I think.

Comment: @Joey: I thought this could work because when I manually click the mouse on the form border (or anywhere else on the form) or if I click the form icon in the taskbar, the form behaves like I expect. I find this strange. Why doesn't Windows activates the form when I do a ShowDialog()?

Comment: After a lot more testing, I noticed the problem only exists when I run the .exe of my application directly. If I run from visual studio, everything works (debug and release)!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

Try `BringToFront()`

```
    var f = new Form1();
    f.Show();
    f.BringToFront();
```

Then just use Select on that control

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        comboBox1.Select();
    }
```

Comment: Because I use f.ShowDialog(), I believe the f.Show() and f.BringToFront() do nothing because the call to f.ShowDialog() blocks until a DialogResult is set? Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're running ShowDialog() from another form it might be worth changing it to: ShowDialog(this) so the new form has the correct parent and the correct blocking behaviour.  Without the 'this' I've seen forms open up behind other forms and other strange behaviour, including focus problems.

Just a thought.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried calling `myComboBox.Focus();`

Just because the form has focus doesn't necessarily mean any control within the form has focus. Also try checking the onKey events of both the form and the individual controls. This normally helps me diagnose what exactly has focus. If the form itself and non on its controls are getting any onKey events then try using `form.Activate();`